# Python requests, авторизация на сайте

Tags: python, python-3.x, авторизация, requests

```
Необходимо авторизоваться на сайте для того, чтобы позже работать с данными.

Сама проблема: сайт для того чтобы авторизоваться составляет POST запрос на другой поддомен, от которого получает Access Token, и, как я понимаю необходимо его запомнить и передать в GET запросе header-а уже нужного поддомена. 

Как такое можно провернуть

Если надо ссылки куда надо дам.
```

UPD. Получил access token с поддомена, делаю новый GET запрос к нужному поддомену, но ничего не выходит.
[image: auth]

Comment: Браузер ведь может сделать нужные запросы с данными (поля, заголовки), скрипт тем более. Добавьте ссылки и ваши попытки. А так, смотрите на запросы браузера и повторите их скриптом, тогда будет работать. А чтобы увидеть запросы requests, используйте этот код: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a7bbd36ba26faa7ade03ffc32d0b5da75a90c53d/requests__examples/view_raw_request.py#L10

Comment: не решили вопрос авторизации? как извлечь цену на товар авторизованного пользователя?

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл причину невозможности авторизации. Всё эти махинации я выполнял на домашнем ноутбуке. Посмотрев запросы с рабочего компьютера, подклбченного к сети от wildberries видно, что браузер получает cookie, когда с другой сети нет. Спасибо за советы, буду биться дальше!)

Answer (score 0):

У wildberries присутствует своё API. Скорее всего у вас получится это сделать только с помощью API

Comment: Ответ полезный, но не рассказывает о том, как пользоваться API, а просто ставит перед фактом что у wildberries. Для подобных емких ответов используйте комментарии.

Comment: К сожалению, api я не нашёл